# How do I remove duplicate files in a folder in windows?

Tags: windows, batch, script, batch-file, batch-rename

Suppose I have two files with same name but different file sizes. Each file has two copies. One with size x. and its copy with size y. where x>y

There are two copies of each file. One with x MB. And other with y MB, where x > y.

```
File a.extension 2 MB (Same name same file type)
File a.extension 1 MB (Same name same file type)
```

I want to keep the file with larger file size. Since there are more than 100 files, I cannot do it manually.

I would like to accomplish this with a batch script.

Comment: What is the common pattern of the files that should be delete? Is it the extension `.f136`?

Comment: Its the size. Each file has two copies. One with size x. and its copy with size y. where x>y @ReddyLutonadio

Comment: Then check this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1290561/delete-duplicate-files-based-on-file-size-with-windows-batch)

Comment: You may want to review your post, and be sure that any relevant scripts are included. They did not appear in your post. If you are using a pre-existing script from another source, please cite it and provide a link as it can help others better understand your question and resources used.

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).